# Missing the second node while printing a list of filenames: why?

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I have a list of the following strings (filenames): `{Lorem.ipsum, dolor-sit-amet, SENDME, LOREM2, consectetur, adipiscing.elit}`.
I wrote this function that is supposed to take each node of the list and generate a single string made of all filenames (interposing `/` between each entry).

```
char *file_list_tostring(struct file_list *file_list) {
    char *final_string = NULL;
    size_t final_len = 0;
    struct file_node *list_iter = file_list->first;
    while (list_iter != NULL) {
        char *tmp = concat(list_iter->filename, "/");
        size_t tmp_len = strlen(tmp);
        char *s = realloc(final_string, final_len + tmp_len + 1); // +1 for '\0'
        if (s == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        final_string = s;
        memcpy(final_string + final_len, tmp, tmp_len + 1);
        final_len += tmp_len;
        list_iter = list_iter->next;
    }
    printf("%s\n", final_string);
    return final_string;
}
```

Here's the implementation of the `concat()` function:

```
char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1); //+1 for the null-terminator
    if (result == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

If I run `file_list_tostring()` I get the following output:

```
Lorem.ipsum/SENDME/LOREM2/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/
```

As you can see, the second entry of the list (`dolor-sit-amet`) is not appearing. That really surprises me! What could the reason be?

**Note:** whatever list of filenames I try, it always skips the second one.

Here's the structures defining the list:

```
struct file_node {
    char *filename;
    struct file_node *prev, *next;
};

struct file_list {
    struct file_node *first, *last;
};
```

#### EDIT

If I add `printf("tmp = %s\n", tmp);` right after `char *tmp = concat(list_iter->filename, "/");` I get the following output:

```
tmp = Lorem.ipsum/
tmp = 
tmp = SENDME/
tmp = LOREM2/
tmp = consectetur/
tmp = adipiscing.elit/
```

Here's a [link](https://pastebin.com/cJPpFcbh) for a program that includes all code I use for this. If I run this test it works as expected... but if I try to run `file_list_print()` on the list generated by my program and later `file_list_tostring` I get different results (as I said earlier, the second entry is missing). I have to suppose that the list is not correctly generated (while it is in the test file instead).

So here's the code I use to get the list (it's supposed to get all filenames in the `repository` directory):

```
struct file_list *get_file_list() {
    struct file_list *list = file_list_init();
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir("./repository");
    if (d == NULL)
        return NULL;
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        struct file_node *newnode;
        if (!(!strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dir->d_name, "..")) && dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
            newnode = file_node_init(dir->d_name);
            file_node_add(list, newnode);
        }
    }
    closedir(d);
    return list;
}
```

I tried changing all files in the directory and this time I get the following 2 outputs:

```
0: FILEC
1: FILEE
2: FILEB
3: FILED
4: FILEA

tmp = FILEC/
tmp = 
tmp = 
tmp = FILED/
tmp = FILEA/

FILEC/FILED/FILEA/
```

Comment: I populated it using `get_file_list()` but I get two different results with `file_list_print()` and `file_list_tostring()` as you can see

Comment: I created a MCVE as you suggested here : https://pastebin.com/uqySHGr3
Funny thing, is that here it works correctly once again! I really don't get what the problem could be... Going on like this I could end up writing all code of my project and I don't think this post would be of some use for stackoverflow :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider how `file_node_init` is implemented:

```
struct file_node *file_node_init(char *filename) {
    struct file_node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct file_node));
    if (node == NULL)           // Error in malloc
        return NULL;
    node->filename = filename;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

Notice that `node->filename` is not allocated, but refers to `d_name` field of `dir` of `get_file_list`. So far so good, yet keep in mind that each `dir` belongs to `d` array, which `opendir` mallocs, but `closedir` *frees*. After `closedir` is called, it ceases to exist, along with everything in it, including names.

Welcome to UB.

Comment: Thansk for your answer! That would definitely explain it :) How do you suggest me to fix it? Editing `file_node_init`?